# How can one prevent a DNS from answering to naked domain requests?

Tags: networking, dns, bind, domain-name

I want my server to answer only to something such as `ping www.david.com`, but not `ping david.com`. Here is my named.conf.local file.

```
zone "david.com" {
    type master;
    file "forward";
};

zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "reverse";
};
```

And the Bind data file, forward:

```
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA dlcsrv.david.com. root.david.com. (
                2   ;   Serial
                604800  ;   Refresh
                86400   ;   Retry
                2419200 ;   Expire
                604800) ;   Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  david.com.
@   IN  A   192.168.1.37
www IN  A   192.168.1.37
ftp IN  A   192.168.1.37
```

What should I change to prevent my DNS server from answering to naked domain requests?

I will appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

"Answering to pings" is not a DNS issue – DNS merely provides mappings to addresses.

If you want specifically to remove the mapping to IP address from the "bare" domain, just remove the corresponding line from your zonefile. In your case, the `@` label refers to the zone root, and `@ IN A 192.168.1.37` is what defines this mapping.

```
@   IN  NS  ns.david.com.
ns  IN  A   192.168.1.37
www IN  A   192.168.1.37
...
```

Comment: if I remove that line I get the following error: `**server can't find www.david.com: SERVFAIL`

Comment: @DAVID You have a self-reference in that `david.com` is its own nameserver. This isn’t a good configuration. You should at least use a subdomain like `ns.david.com`. Currently, the resolver arrives at the fact that `david.com` is supposed to be the nameserver, but it doesn’t have an IP address.

Comment: @DanielB, changing david.com to ns.david.com still allows me to do requests via the naked domain.

Comment: If it'll let you, I'd suggest using 0.0.0.0 as the IP for the root record.
`@ IN A 0.0.0.0`

Comment: What's the point in that?